# begin_fill doesn't fill anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am making  a turtle program. I need to make the fill blue, Using `begin_fill` and `end_fill`. However, everytime I fill it, it fills black. How to make a shape fill any other color, such as blue? In case you have guessed, this is the indian flag. Here is my code:

`

```
from turtle import *
pensize(180)
penup()
speed(1000)
setpos(-220, -220)
pencolor("green")
shape(name = "turtle")
down()
fd(420)
left(90)
penup()
fd(90)
left(90)
fd(490)
right(90)
fd(100)
right(90)
fd(60)
down()
pencolor("white")
fd(450)
left(90)
penup()
fd(100)
left(90)
fd(490)
left(90)
fd(40)
left(180)
fd(40)
right(90)
fd(40)
down()
pencolor("orange")
fd(450)
penup()
right(90)
fd(100)
right(90)
fd(225)
down()
pencolor("blue")
pensize(10)
circle(50)
left(90)
penup()
fd(20)
right(90)
pendown()
begin_fill("blue")
circle(30)
end_fill("blue")
```

`
Please answer!!
Also, if you run this, the black middle, should be blue. PLz help!!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to improve the title. The *turtle-graphics* tag already tells us you're making a turtle program. Your title should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking, and should be clear enough to be of use to a future site user who is looking through a list of search results. Also, this question is pretty easy to answre using the [Turtle Graphics documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle)

Comment: Wecome to SO!  As a note--it helps if you cut your code shorter, as short as you can so it still replicates the issue you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` commands don't take a *color* argument -- in fact they don't take *any* arguments.  You need to use `color()` or `fillcolor()` to do what you want.  I've reworked your code below with this fix along with shortening it a bit turtle-command-wise.

I've also added a patch at the top of the code that turns the ends of lines from being round to being rectangular.  I find it helps with drawing flags with a fat pen.  It could cause you trouble in the remaining drawing you need to do:

```
from turtle import *
import tkinter as _

_.ROUND = _.BUTT

shape(name="turtle")
speed('fastest')
pensize(180)
penup()

pencolor("green")
setpos(-220, -220)
pendown()
forward(450)
penup()

setpos(-220, -20)

pencolor("white")
pendown()
forward(450)
penup()

setpos(-220, 80)

pencolor("orange")
pendown()
forward(450)
penup()

right(90)
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(225)

pencolor("blue")
pensize(10)
pendown()
circle(50)
penup()

left(90)
forward(20)
right(90)

color("blue")
pendown()
begin_fill()
circle(30)
end_fill()

hideturtle()
done()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `color("blue")`:

```
...
color("blue")
begin_fill()
circle(30)
end_fill()
```